# JSOUP and Android Emulator - unable to resolve host

Tags: java, android, apache, wamp, jsoup

I have virtual host on my Windows 8 - http://test.localhost to my localhost on wamp and test site. If i use this address in browsers then all working well.

If i use this in jsoup and my android apps:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://test.localhost").post();
```

Then I have warning:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "test.localhost": No address associated with hostname
```

How can I connect by jsoup with my localhost and Android emulator?

EDIT:

URLs from Internet, for example stackoverflow.com etc working fine. I would like connect emulator with my localhost.

Comment: Yes, I would like use my vhost on this emulator.

Comment: make sure your browser is able to open the site from your localhost. BTW 10.0.2.2 is localhost ip for connecting with emulator. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Android emulator is a Virtual Machine which has a network stack that is separate from your Windows machine. If Android did have DNS set to resolve `test.localhost`, it would resolve to itself, not to your Windows host.

You need to use your Windows local IP in the URL. Something like:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://192.168.0.1").post();
```

You can get your local IP with `cmd -> ipconfig`

You can check that the Android emulator VM can connect through the network to your host with `adb shell ping <ip>`